# Why do I get an error while compiling IronRuby in Ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby, installation, ironruby

I can't seem to compile ironruby in ruby 1.8.7. I always get this error:

*no such file to load -- windows/path*

Does this mean that ironruby is not compatible with ruby 1.8.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the gem windows-pr is required before the pathname2 stuff succeeds.  I did a `gem install windows-pr` in my Ruby 1.8.7 install and then was successfully able to run `rake --tasks` in IronRuby (it previously failed with the same "no such file to load" error).

Comment: Thanks, I need both pathname2 and windows-pr. :)

Answer (score 1):

IronRuby itself does not require any ruby interpreter to be installed.  So asking if it's compatible with MRI 1.8.7 is a bit of a misnomer.  What this sounds like is that 1.8.7 does not include a library that the Rakefile uses.

As an aside, IronRuby does target 1.8.6 compatiblity.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I think rake does locate for a specific gem that is not available in Ruby 1.8.7. T_T

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you need to install the gem pathname2 in your ruby 1.8.7 install.